# Rearrange structure arrays of uneven lengths to single 1d array

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, structure

I've got an struct array, with three fields - an array, the array's length, and a number.

```
N = 5;
data = struct;
for i=1:N
    n = ceil(rand * 3);
    data(i).len = n;
    data(i).array = rand(1,n);
    data(i).number = i;
end
```

The data looks like this:

```
data = 
1x5 struct array with fields:
    len    = [ 1 3 3 1 1 ]
    array  = [[0.8]; [0.7 0.9 0.4]; [0.7 0 0.3]; [0.1]; [0.3]]
    number = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]
```

I can return array as a 1x9 array in several ways:

```
>>> [data.array] 
>>> cat(2,data.array)
[0.8 | 0.7 0.9 0.4 | 0.7 0 0.3 | 0.1 | 0.3]     %  | shows array separation
```

I'd like to repeat the number (`data.number`) `len` times, to produce the same length array as the concatenated array.

I'm currently doing this with `arrayfun` then `cell2mat`:

```
>> x = arrayfun(@(x) repmat(x.number, 1, x.len), data, 'UniformOutput', false)
x = 
    [1]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [4]    [5]
>> cell2mat(x)
[ 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5]
```

This makes the numbers line up with the arrays.

```
arrays =  [ 0.8 | 0.7 0.9 0.4 | 0.7 0 0.3 | 0.1 | 0.3 ] 
numbers = [ 1   | 2   2   2   | 3   3   3 | 4   | 5   ]
```

---

The idea behind this is to feed the data to the GPU for processing - but rearranging the data takes orders of magnitude longer than the actual processing.

`Arrayfun` takes ~5 seconds when N=100,000, and a for loop calling `repmat` takes ~4 seconds.

Is there a faster way to rearrange data from uneven arrays in structures into matching length 1d arrays? I'm open to using a different data structure.

---

**Testing vectorised method:**

```
data = struct;
data(1).len = 1;
data(1).array = [1 2 3];
data(1).number = 11;
data(2).len = 0;
data(2).array = [];
data(2).number = 12;
data(3).len = 2;
data(3).array = [4 5 6; 7 8 9];
data(3).number = 13;

list_of_array = cat(1,data.array)

idx = zeros(1,size(list_of_array,1));
% Set start of each array to 1
len = cumsum([data.len])
idx(len) = 1
% Flat indices
idx = cumsum([1 idx(1:end-1)])

nf = [data.number]
repeated_num_faces = nf(idx)
```

Gives the output:

```
list_of_array =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
len =
     1     1     3    % Cumulative lengths
idx =
     1     0     1    % Ones at start
idx =
     1     2     2    % Flat indexes - should be [1 3 3]
nf =
    11    12    13    % Numbers expanded
repeated_num_faces =
    11    12    12    % Wrong .numbers - should be [11 13 13]
```

Comment: Ok. The vectorized code will work for empty `data.array` if you assure that when `data(i).array` is empty, the `data(i).number` is empty as well. Otherwise the number mapping is inconsistent with the array lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `struct` is not the easiest to deal with here. Definitely, you should not use `repmat`. Rather than that, preallocate the `data_number` array and do a `for` loop:

```
tic;
data_array  = [data(:).array];
data_number = zeros(size(data_array));
start = 1;
for i=1:N
    nel = data(i).len;
    data_number(start:start+nel-1) = data(i).number;
    start = start+nel;
end
toc;
```

Here is another 'vectorized' solution using `cumsum` to mark the indices in the 'flat' vector

```
tic;
data_array  = [data.array];
data_number = zeros(size(data_array));

% cumulative sum of number of elements in every array
len = cumsum([data.len]);

% mark the end of every array in a 'flat' vector
data_number(len) = 1;

% compute 'flat' indices for every data(i).array
data_number = cumsum([1 data_number(1:end-1)]);

% extract the data.number field
data_num = [data.number];
data_number = data_num(data_number);
toc;
```

For a data set of `N=1e5` the times are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.153539 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.110694 seconds.
```

Comment: `0.35s` on mine, using 1e5 points! Much better - thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexL You might want to correct the code - there was a `-1` missing. I have also added a similar performing 'vectorized' version.

Comment: In your 'vectorised' solution, am I correct in thinking that you assume that `.number` is it's index in the array?

Comment: @AlexL Yes! good point. But in your example it actually is simply `i`, so I guess I forgot about the data.number. Do you need this fixed? It can be done.

Comment: In my real (not example) code it isn't, unfortunately. I'm currently using repmat because my `.number` is a `1x3 double` which I split up into three 1x`.len` arrays (one for each x,y,z). I think you're right, using `data_number_x(...) = data(i).number(1) etc`
 in a loop as you've said would be faster. (So don't worry about the vectorised solution, unless you'd like to!)

Comment: @AlexL I have updated my answer - since those are just indices it is trivial to extract the `data.number` values. But it does seem like loop is faster.

Comment: @AlexL I have overlooked that you actually store the length of every `data(i).array` in `len`. This makes things much simpler and faster :) Have a look at the updated solutions. Vectorized code is now faster.

Comment: I've discovered a bug in the vectorised method! If we have a 3x1 structure, and `data(2).len = 0`, then idx will be `[1 1 1 1 2 2 2]`, rather than `[1 1 1 1 3 3 3]`. Any ideas? I spent a good few hours finding this one!

Comment: @AlexL Yes, I see your point :) But in the way you presented the problem all data entries have at least one element (`n` is greater than 0 always). So strictly speaking, this is not a bug. You just have a different problem definition than you presented in the question. Anyway, no ideas at this moment. I have no time right now. Just use the loop version. It is fast enough.

Comment: Haha no worries, just thought I'd let everyone know in case their use was similar to mine. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @AlexL actually, did you try the most recent code? I think there should be no problem now. Can you run it again with the most recent version?

Comment: I've added a simple demonstration in my question. I'll fix it, don't worry about it if you're busy!